# How to automatically enter input in readline() instead of manually entering it at the console in R?

Tags: r

I have a `readline()` function in a for loop

For Simplicity let's say I have this code:

```
x <- character()
for (i in 1:500)  x[i] <- readline('Enter Value')
```

How can I automatically enter input instead of manually entering it at the console 500 times?

Comment: You should probably do something like `x[i] <- sample(1:10,1, replace =TRUE)` or `x[i] <- 10`. If you want to assign a value to `x[i]` calculated in the loop, assign that output to `x[i]`, e.g. `x[i] <- paste0("Loop Iteration :", i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readline()` isn't intended for automatic input. From `?readline`:

> Description
>
> `readline` reads a line from the terminal (in interactive use).

and:

> Details
>
> The prompt string will be truncated to a maximum allowed length,
>   normally 256 chars (but can be changed in the source code).
>
> This can only be used in an interactive session.

Looking at `?interactive` we can read the following:

> An interactive R session is one in which it is assumed that there is a
>   human operator to interact with, so for example R can prompt for
>   corrections to incorrect input or ask what to do next or if it is OK
>   to move to the next plot.

So, basically you are trying to use `readline` for something it isn't intended for.

Comment: well then I guess that's resolved; I 'll have to think of a more sophisticated way to input my data

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize this command, assuming you're looking to fill the column with the same value.  If that's not what you're trying to do, I'm confused as to what you want.  Run my example below and say whether that's the kind of thing you're looking for

```
working <- iris
head(working)
working$like <- readline("Do you like this flower?  ")
head(working)
```

Comment: no this is not what I was looking for, my situation is totally different, I do not want to fill a column, I need to input the arguments of a function

Comment: In that case, Jaap is correct in that you're not using `readline` as intended.  If there's any semblance of pattern to your arguments, generate a vector (eg, `c(rep("bongos", 10), rep("beavers", 15))`) and have your function perform different tasks depending on whether it reads `bongos` or `beavers`

Comment: it is a bit more sophisticated than that; because I don't know what are the cases

Comment: If you can provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data and intended format, we may be able to help with that.  But saying you want to "automatically enter input" narrows it down to...well, quite a lot of entry possibilities, let alone ways to interpret those values down the line